# How do I disable the height of the body to be more than 100% when I drag inside the body?

Tags: html, css

I want to actually disable the dragging inside the body of the html. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Maybe the code you have currently?

Comment: what do you mean by "dragging"? do you mean scrolling?

Comment: No I mean literally dragging with the mouse down inside the body of the HTML

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem? Perhaps in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a leap here and assume you're asking how to stop an HTML element from placing a scrollbar on itself?

I believe the CSS property you're looking for is `overflow`

Try the example below:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No I do need a scroll bar. My problem is if I drag from the top to bottom in the body, part of the body moves up and only the half body is visible. I want to stop the movement of the body on dragging

Comment: This sounds like something unique to your web page, browser, or local machine. Typically when I click in the body of a web page and drag down, it just selects the elements on the page. Can you share your code or url to see your issue?

Comment: Actually i want to stop the text selection by dragging the mouse. The problem here is, because of some fixed elements present on top, the total height becomes more than 100%. This causes drag of the whole body when text is selected.

Comment: I have to use it for IE8. So can't use "user-select:none"